# How to fix DiscordAPIError: Unknown Member?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have had a discord bot running for about 3 months, and today I started getting this `DiscordAPIError: Unknown Member` error message.  It is coming from an interaction:

```
  client.on("interactionCreate", async interaction => {
    interaction.member.roles.add(<roleId>);
  });
```

I am unable to consistently reproduce the error, but it seems like it may be coming from new members joining the server, and perhaps the discord API is not recognizing them as a guild member just yet.  The server had a large influx of users today, and that's when the issue started.

Is there any way I can work around this issue, or perhaps force update the guild's member list?

Comment: Do you have GuildMembers intent?

Comment: I do, yes.  Again, it did work until recently, so it must have something to do with volume (we had a large influx of users today), unless discordjs changed something in the past 24 hrs

Comment: do you have the `USER` partial enabled?

Comment: That I don't, I can give it a shot!

Comment: Try using `await interaction.member.fetch()` above it

Comment: This worked, thank you!

Comment: I may have spoke to soon - this seems to have made the problem a bit better, but it is still happening

Answer (score 0):

The member does not seem to be properly cached. Before accessing it, use `await interaction.member.fetch()`

```js
client.on("interactionCreate", async interaction => {
    await interaction.member.fetch()
    interaction.member.roles.add(roleId)
})
```